# Open Serial Port with variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to open a COM port in my powershell script:

```
function openComPort($number, $baud) {
    $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM$number", $baud, "None", 8, "One")
    $port.Open()
    return $port
}
$myOpenedPort = openComPort(1, 9600)
```

This fails with

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "5" argument(s): "Positive number required.
Parameter name: BaudRate"
At line:9 char:20
+     $port = New-Object <<<<  System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM$number", $baud, "None", 8, "One")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:11 char:12
+     $port.Open <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Open:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your function wrong, Powershell (unlike other languages) doesn't require brackets when calling a function, see [about_functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6) for further info.

Using them like that groups everything inside the brackets into a single item, this is being sent to the first parameter `$number`, leaving `$baud` empty - which is causing your errors.

The correct syntax is:

```
openComPort 1 9600
```

---

EDIT: It's also good practice to have your params into a `param()` block (this is a step towards using [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced).

And to also set a param type to ensure you receive the correct input type. They are both `int` in this case - as you only want a positive whole number.

This would update your function to:

```
function openComPort {
    Param(
        [int]$number,
        [int]$baud
    )

    $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM$number", $baud, 'None', 8, 'One')
    $port.Open()
    return $port
}
$myOpenedPort = openComPort -number 1 -baud 9600
```